# How much memory will be occupied by a null value in a DB?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering how much memory does a null value occupy in a database can anyone answer clearly?

Comment: Depends on the database - IE SQL Server: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/06/How_does_SQL_Server_really_store_NULL-s.aspx

Comment: NULL is not a value - it's the **absence** of a value. Shouldn't be occupying any space at all (since there is nothing to store, really....)

Comment: **Memory**? Don't you confuse it with disk storage? And what dbms do you use?

Comment: @marc_s: you're completely wrong ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I'm pretty sure marc_s was making a joke.

Comment: I highly suggest reasking this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @zerkms Trust me, too many people confuse memory with disk usage.

Comment: I wonder if CJ Date dies a little inside every time a question like this gets asked. A NULL question and storage question in one

Comment: @Conard Frix No theoritically marc_s may be wrong but practically he is right how database knows whether an entry is null it should have something like flag to say its a null.

Answer (score 5):

How much space it takes up depends on what the column is defined to be and on the storage engine being used. Some data types take a fixed amount of space regardless of the data stored. There is a small space penalty for declaring a column to accept NULL. Details can be found in [this general discussion in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html) and more in the docs about each storage engine.